# Restrict wordpress user access to specific posts by acf field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm searching for a solution to only give access to specific posts within a custom post-type to user, who is assigned with this post by an acf field.

Examples:

- my cpt is called "homes"
- the acf field (on the user page) is called "home_linked_user" and is a relationship object. here i choose all homes I would like to link to the user
- the user should only get access to the homes related to his user page

Can anybody help me to set this up? I have already tried to find similar ideas, but did not found a working solution for my problem. Does it even work?

Comment: to answer your last question yes this would work.

What you need to search for is:

- WP hooks that run when the post is getting loaded 
- How to get the logged in user info from wordpress 
- redirect user if his user info (acf) doesn't match the acf on the post

I can help you more if you can share your acf code for the post and the users